# crabbly / Print.js Print not working, Print Preview not showing

Tags: reactjs, printjs

We are using 1.6 of crabbly/Print.js
https://github.com/crabbly?tab=repositories
https://printjs.crabbly.com/

It works just fine until this setting in edge is turned on. This is our code.

```
                const bytes = convertBase64ToUint8Array(json.contentBase64)
                const blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: json.contentType });
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                showMessage.success('Sucessfully downloaded the report as pdf', url)
                print({ printable: url, type: 'pdf', showModal: true })
```

[image]

This is the error we are getting. I cannot reproduce this in development.
[image]

Comment: it is not clear to me how that needs to be done. I am using react with print.js. I don't have access to the iframe. iframe is within the print.js library.

Comment: @ l -_- l: hello. I tried some things like <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="blob:http://localhost" />. Did you have anything specific in mind for disabling same origin
    <

Comment: No I was wrong about disabling it directly via the browser

Comment: Have you tried getting the file using ` printJS(URL.createObjectURL(file))` ?